# Tipografía web en móvil

Tags: html, css, fuentes

Tengo este pequeño problema con una tipografía para la web.

Adjunto primera imagen en la que se ve bien desde el inspector de elementos con el visor de dispositivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí con un móvil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, la parte inferior de la M se corta.

HTML:

```
<div class="fullWidth">
    <div class="header-section matricula">
        <img src="imgs/header/menu.png" class="menu-button" data-open="imgs/header/cancel.png" data-close="imgs/header/menu.png">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                Matrícula
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fullWidth .header-section .title {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
.fullWidth .header-section .title h1 {
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "BacktoBlackDemo";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

**Soluciones probadas:**

- Propiedad `overflow` como `auto` o `visible`.
- Propiedad `line-height` muy por encima, o `normal` pero no ha resultado para que
  no se corte la fuente.
- Propiedad `height`. En cierto modo funcionaba, he puesto tanto la
  caja como el h1 con la altura de la cabecera pero sigue cortando el
  título en la misma línea.

¿Tal vez la tipografía es la culpable, o algo que me necesite en las CSS de más que me haya olvidado?

Comment: Haz probado con un height?

Comment: @Cig voy a probar!

Comment: @Cig Parece ser que si al final, merci, si pones como respuesta te la doy como buena!

Comment: @blonfu lo he probado, incluso poner 500px, pero no hay manera. He probado con el height, al principio funcionaba, pero el texto se colocaba arriba, fue moverlo hacia abajo, y al llegar a ese mismo punto, lo corta

Comment: tienes una liga donde ver el error?

Comment: @Cheshire sí, he borrado mi comentario porque he visto en tu pregunta que ya habías probado eso, no lo había leído bien la primera vez

Comment: como dice @MarcosGallardo ¿podrías crear un ejemplo que reproduzca el problema? Sería mucho más fácil buscar una solución

Comment: @blonfu me gustaría, pero al tener la página en un "http" sin la "s" bloquea el request de la fuente, y en google fonts no está la tipo.

Comment: Usando [`Remote debugging`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) y especificando `line-height: normal; height: 116px;` pude [ver la letra completa solo que mal ubicada](https://s23.postimg.org/4369vrvez/image.png).

Answer (score 1):

Sólo quita el `overflow` en el `.title` y del `h1`:

```
.fullWidth .header-section .title {
  /* overflow: auto; // Es probable que esto te estorbe*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
.fullWidth .header-section .title h1 {
  /* overflow: auto; // Es probable que esto te estorbe*/
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "BacktoBlackDemo";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 120px;
  line-height: 1em; /* Éste sugiero que lo cambies a 1em (120px) o 1.2em (144px) para que se ajuste automáticamente dependiendo del tamaño de tu tipografía. */
}
```

El `overflow` sirve para cortar el contenido, renderizar una scrollbar o para mostrar el contenido aún cuando sobresalga su contenedor superior. [Aquí la explicación completa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, anteriormente no tenía el overflow en ninguno de ambos, lo puse para comprobar que no fuera que la tipo por alguna razón estaba sobresaliendo y se ocultaba y tal, pero no, y el line-height he probado también con esos valores, pero no ha habido suerte. Me comentan que puede deberse a la configuración de la tipografía en si misma

Comment: Tienes alguna url donde se pueda comprobar o puedes crear un ejemplo con el error en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) para poder encontrar más rápido el error? Por la imagen que muestras no creo que sea problema de la tipografía. Estoy 99% seguro que es un problema con el overflow.

Comment: jsfiddle imposible por el momento. tengo la página hospedada en un "http" sin la "s", por lo que bloquea el request. Ahora mismo está subida una versión con la "M" en minúscula, y la página tiene un user/pass.

Comment: @Cheshire necesitamos mayor información o no vamos a poder encontrar el problema exacto que está ocurriendo. Considera crear un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el siguiente código css:

```
line-height: normal;
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo, ahora actualizaré el post

Comment: Buscando soluciones, mencionan que puede ser problema de la fuente, un valor de **descender**. Para lo que la única solución que dan es que se cambie ese valor en el archivo de la fuente.

Comment: vaya, el único archivo que podía abrir era el .svg de la fuente, cambié ese valor tanto a mayor como a menor, pero no vi ningún cambio

Comment: Según leí el que creo la fuente es el que debería hacer esos cambios, no sé si en el ttf o en cual archivo

Comment: Ok, merci por la ayuda!